# Excel Keystroke shortcut; Appending Text At End Of Current cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of highly similar, but not identical, items in a column.

The first 30 or 40 bytes (actually characters, these cells are text strings that describe other cells) are all the same, e.g. "Send signal from MCU to LED"

The rest of the bytes are unique, e.g., "#3, Back Window closed"

The column will look something like this...

```
Send signal from MCU to LED #3, Back Window closed
Send signal from MCU to LED #4, Back Door Locked
Send signal from MCU to LED #5, Carport Door closed
Send signal from MCU to LED #6, Carport Light Off
```

Is there a simple way for me to navigate this from the keyboard, so that I don't have to use the mouse and click on each individual cell ?

I would like to move the keyboard arrows, hit some key sequence sort of thing, and start typing with my cursor at the end of the text string in that cell.

After that, I would like to hit  `ENTER` and use the arrow keys to get to the next cell, and so on and so on.

Comment: Why do you use the word bytes? Did you mean characters?

Comment: @DaveRook they are actually characters, these cells are text strings that describe other cells.  I have edited the original question, in case that might have been a point of confusion for some readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a cell selected, you can press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the text entry field inside the cell. The cursor will go to the end by default. After you've finished editing, hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to go down to the next row (or the next cell in the range, if you have selected a range). You can change this behaviour by going to **Options** > **Advanced** (in Excel 2007/2010) - the option is first on that list.

Comment: Perfect; the answer. Plus one and the checkmark. Just curious; where do I find the `Options` menu ?  I don't see it on my (2007) copy of Excel

Comment: Click the Office "globe" in the upper left of the Excel window, then click Options.

Comment: @Benshepherd, got it. thanks.  Exactly what I needed to know, and extra help above and beyond